# How to get super_attribute from checkout/cart

Tags: magento

In function

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getItems() as $item) {
    $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
    $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
}
```

Now i can get

```
$product_id = $item->getProduct()->getId(); / product
$quote_id = $item->getId(); / cart
$quote_qty = $item->getQty(); / cart
```

But, How i can get super_attribute from $item

https://i.stack.imgur.com/79sXX.png

I want to get Supper_attribute for Url
checkout/cart/add/product/$productId/?super_attribute[**attribute_ID**]=**option_ID**&qty;=$quote_qty

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
$super_attribute = $item->getProduct()->getSuperAttribute();
```

Comment: print_r($super_attribute); is return **1**